# Tomcat error HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I copied my project in Tomcat in the Web App folder in a subdirectory.
It doesn't seem to be able to find the servlets!!!

Link:
    http://localhost:8084/Amirhosein/MyServlet

Error: HTTP Status [404] – [Not Found]

[image: View]

Web.xml:

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.royalvas.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.royalvas.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The default port for Tomcat is 8080. Check Tomcat's configuration.
2. Try to change your mapping to *. Currently I think you set the mapping to MyServlet, so your servlet's path might be /MyServlet/MyServlet

Comment: I changed the default port to 8084 - I changed the mapping but still has a problem